# How to Debug the code located remotely

Tags: eclipse, jetty

I am working on a web Application .
I am using Eclipse and Jetty 7 as Web Server for this Application .
I make changes to the code and deploy it to a Linux Machine which is remotely located .

After deployment i access  the Application through browser using `http://10.56.345:8080/MViewer`
My question is , Is it possible to debug in this case ??

Please Share your views .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Remote debugger in eclispe. You can set that using proper connection parameters in Eclipse Remote debug configuration

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much , on the common tab do i need to do any settings ??